# Selenium iterate same url

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, iteration

I trying to iterate with selenium, all user from a twitter's followers list but my loop repeat the same url :

[image]

```
browser.get('https://twitter.com/getFANDOM/followers')
sleep(2) 


elems = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div//div//a[@class="css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l"]').get_attribute('href')


followers = []

for i in range(12):
    followers.append(elems)
```

[image]

Comment: seems to me that You are finding just one element

Comment: @Matiiss my "a" class it for all "href" on this page

Comment: go over all anchor tags and get href individually from them

Comment: if I do that my loop will be useless

Comment: wait, actually looking at the loop it seems to already be pretty useless, You have to iterate over `elems` not in a range, try `for i in elems:` and append i to the list

Comment: i try this, i have same error

Comment: for i in elems(12):
        followers.append([i])

Comment: that is certainly not how You should do that: because `elems(12)` is a function call with an argument of int 12, just `for i in elems: followers.append(i)` anyhow it doesn't even look like that `elems` even contains all the links, either it gets always the first one (because `.get_attribute()` returns the first value and if so loop over each anchor tag inside the `elems` and get href individually from them)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `browser.find_element_by_xpath` use `browser.find_elements_by_xpath` then you will get a list of elements which you can iterate.

Please make sure the `xpath` is correct and returns the list.

Comment: Im checking my elems , but it doesen't work

elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div//div//a[@class="css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l"]').get_attribute('href')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: Your initial question was different

Comment: I would answer it, but first make sure you ask the exact question, not many questions in one.

Comment: Also, I guess people don't want to answer you because you do not accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach to get all the followers of the profile. Instead of finding the url which you are having trouble with, you can scrape their usernames which are starting with @ which are easier to scrape. e.g. @ButacaMecanica for the first in the pic. Once you scrape all usernames, then you can easily generate the url of the profile. Twitter follows specific url pattern for every profile i.e. https://twitter.com/username

So, what you will do is scrape all the usernames and replace/remove @ and concate with this url https://twitter.com/  to generate the profile link.

Now lets come to the issue you are having:

What you are doing is getting only one element by css selector and href attribute of that same single element. So, "elems" contain only one href attribute. Then in your for loop you are appending the list with "elems" which contain only one url. So, appending one url 12 times and you can see the result.

What you need to do is, just get all the elements first in elems like this:

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div//div//a[@class="css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l"]')    #use find elements
followers = []
for elem in elems:
    followers.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
```

In your case you were not iterating the elems. That should be like this:

```py
    for i in range(12):
        followers.append(elems[i].get_attribute('href'))
```

I hope this will help.