# Selenium - ".text" Unresolved attribute reference 'text' for class 'list'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/information/#text-content

According to Selenium, it said:

```
# Navigate to url
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

# Retrieves the text of the element
text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1").text
```

But when I follow this rule, it shows Unresolved attribute reference 'text' for class 'list'.

```
vegetables_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "info-wrapper").text
```

I don't know what's going on. When I don't put ".text". Everything gets fine and shows:

```
Product_Name:[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0aedd6c6d1e0371c2781854606db200", element="6c140c85-242b-45fe-bf45-5217d7d979c1")>]
Original_Price:[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0aedd6c6d1e0371c2781854606db200", element="2c646052-c91e-41a2-b7f8-125240dd449b")>]
Product_Price:[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0aedd6c6d1e0371c2781854606db200", element="2edec63b-56e2-49e7-963f-e96d41beabcd")>]
```

This is my code:

```
#data setting
vegetables_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "info-wrapper")

for search in vegetables_search:
 Product_name = search.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "h4")
 Original_price = search.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "promotional")
 Product_price = search.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "price")

 print(f'Product_Name:{Product_name}\nOriginal_Price:{Original_price}\nProduct_Price:{Product_price}')
 print(" ")
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I want to change "selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement" into text. Thankyou.

Comment: ```driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "info-wrapper")``` returns a list, which doesn't have the ```text``` attribute.

Comment: what's the actual url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_elements` method returns a **list** of `WebElement` objects while `find_element` method returns a **single** `WebElement` object.
`text` method can be applied on a single `WebElement` object to extract it text content.
`text` method can not be applied on a list of objects.
You should use `find_element` there, as following:

```py
#data setting
vegetables_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "info-wrapper")

for search in vegetables_search:
 Product_name = search.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h4").text
 Original_price = search.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "promotional").text
 Product_price = search.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "price").text

 print(f'Product_Name:{Product_name}\nOriginal_Price:{Original_price}\nProduct_Price:{Product_price}')
 print(" ")
```

Or in case these are expected to be a list of elements - iterate over the lists and apply `text` method on each element in the list.

Comment: It works, thanks. But I wonder how can I print readable texts if I want to search in "elements".

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67170094/selenium-iterate-same-url" Just like this scenario. This OP ran the same result(links) because of using "find_element".

Comment: @hectorcchan this your question about printing a readable texts is not clear enough. Also, now it's another, new question. I think we answered the question you asked here. So, please accept the answer here and then ask a new, separate question about printing texts problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'text' for class 'list'
```

...implies that there is no attribute as *`text`* for `list` type objects.

`driver.find_elements*` returns a *list*, where as *`text`* is a WebElement attribute. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

To print the texts from the *`(By.CLASS_NAME, "info-wrapper")`* classes, you can use [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "info-wrapper")])
  ```

Comment: Isn't the original problem because the OP was accessing the ```text``` attribute on a ```list``` result?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
vegetables_search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "info-wrapper")
print(vegetables_search.text)
```

Or if it doesn't bring everything then,

```
use vegetables_search.get_attribute("textContent")
```